# Execute sicklms 5xx

Tags: ros, sick

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

first of all I'm new to ROS and tried to read as much as I can the tutorials.
I successfully installed ROS Jade on my Ubuntu 15.04.

Now i want to use our Scanner Sick LMS 511.
So i found this thread (http://answers.ros.org/question/86246/how-to-use-lms5xx-in-ros/)  with the fork drivers on ROS Answers and tried to install and run them.
To install I used following commands:

```
cd ~/catkin_ws/src/  
git clone -b master https://github.com/rhuitl/laser_drivers.git
cd ..
rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --rosdistro jade
catkin_make
catkin_make install
```

After doing that i also added the Path to ROS_PACKAGE_PATH editing `.bashrc`.
After typing `echo $ROS_PACKAGE` i get :
/home/senintel/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper2/ros/sicklms:/home/senintel/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper2

So I hope the path should be right.
Now when i try to run the scanner with:

```
rosrun sicktoolbox_wrapper2 sicklms_5xx
```

I get following error :

```
[rosrun] Couldn't find executable named sicklms_5xx below /home/senintel/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper2
```

Now I have no Idea why i get this error. Can anyone help me please?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229752/execute-sicklms-5xx/) by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2016-03-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> After doing that i also added the Path to `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` editing `.bashrc`

Don't do that. It's very rare that you have to setup / change `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` by hand.

Based on the commands you listed, do a

```
source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Then try `rosrun` again.

You basically added the directory with just the sources to your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH`: there are no executables there, so the error `rosrun` gave you makes perfect sense.

---

Edit:

> I removed the line from `.bashrc` and used your command.
> I still get the same error like before.

> Searching packages with `rospack find sicktoolbox2/sicktoolbox_wrapper2` are linked to
> `/home/senintel/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox2`

Looking at the packages in the github repository you [linked](https://github.com/rhuitl/laser_drivers), it appears they are rosbuild packages, not catkin. So `catkin_make [install]` won't actually build them. If you want to use them on Jade, you can only do that from a rosbuild overlay workspace.

---

Edit2: I'm not sure about LMS5xx support, but I would at least go for a catkin-ized version of those packages: `rhuitl/laser_drivers` seems rather outdated. Even [ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper](https://github.com/ros-drivers/sicktoolbox_wrapper) has been catkinized. Status is a bit unclear, but [clearpathrobotics/laser_drivers](https://github.com/clearpathrobotics/laser_drivers) appears to have nodes for LMS5xx. Perhaps you can salvage something from there.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on 2016-03-21**:
Hello thank you for your answer first of all.

I removed the line from `.bashrc` and used your command.
I still get the same error like before.

Searching packages with `rospack find sicktoolbox2/sicktoolbox_wrapper2` are linked to
`/home/senintel/catkin_ws/src/laser_drivers/sicktoolbox2`

**Comment by [anonymous26353](https://answers.ros.org/users/26353/anonymous26353/) on 2016-03-21**:
You sir are a genius! :D
Like u said, i found the outdated version.
So i used the last link from u and run the commands again
Now it is starting.

Thank you so much! :)